# SQLite select x-th row

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, rowid

let's suppose I have this table, where I deleted the row with rowid=3:

```
rowid | something
------+-----------
    1 | ...
    2 | ...
    4 | ...
    5 | ...
```

How to select the third row (the one with rowid=4) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select * from table limit 2,1`

Means something like "start from index 2 and return 1 row."

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from yourtable order by rowid limit 1 offset 2;
```

Will get you the third row in that sorted result set (offset is 0-based).

Answer (score -1):

select Max(row_id) from (
select * from table_name limit 3)